# Posting two games with same bundle identifier

Tags: game-center

i am using game center into my app only for the leaderboard. I planned to release the app in two different mode(free and premium). Can i able to have two apps with same name and bundle identifer? if not is there is any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the bundle identifier.  It must be unique.  If you try to load one version, it will wipe the other.

If you want to do two apps, just change the bundle identifier.  iirc you can still use the same name for both.

Comment: if i change the bundle identifier it will post the scores in two different accounts. I need to maintain a common leaderboard for both game(free and premium). Is there is any another way to do this using game center.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve a common leaderboard for the both free and premium version of the game using game center

Comment: @user691106 game center also goes by bundle identifier.  The best way to do it is to just make the premium version an in-app purchase (so that both use the same bundle).

Answer (score 0):

Even the correct answer is no it's not possible to use the same BundleID BUT as I assume you'd like to use the same leader board for both apps, and this is possible!
From iOS 6 you can use Game Center Group and both or more apps could feed the same group leader boards or achievements.